# How can i tell a Parent Window to refresh its grid from a dialog?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an Grid witch is based on Angular Material which has an Edit option. If user clicks on edit i open the form using mat-dialog. If user now try's to close the form i open another dialog asking him if he wants to svae the changed data or not. If he elects save i will save the data to my backend via api which all works fine and both mat-dialogs are closed and i am back on the grid. What i want to be able to do is to go and tell the grid to refresh so the saved changes are reflected.

Here is the Code i use in my Edit form

```
close() {
      if (this.bucketForm.dirty) {
        const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(DialogComponent,
          { disableClose: true,
            data: { message : 'Are you sure you want to Exit without saving your changes ?', title : 'Unsaved Changes' }
          });

        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe( result => {
          if (result === true) {
            console.log('Will do an ' + this.submitText + ' ' + this.docID);
            this.saveUpdade();

            this.dialogRef.close();


                } else {
                  this.dialogRef.close();
                }
            });

      } else {
        this.dialogRef.close();
      }
  }
```

Comment: I typical web form in a dialog hase two buttons: Cancel and Save(Submit). If the user press Cancel or in some cases the area outside the dialog it means cancel. Why should a second dialog appear?.

Comment: If you use Save and cancel buttons, which is standard, your second dialog introduce a logic problem. Its a question if you would like to save(submit). But the user just choose cancel

Comment: For the simple reason that my form has a Save or Update Button and a Close / Exit one. User can only close the form via Button. Now if the user edited some data on the form before i allow him to exit i ask if he is sure he does not want to save the unsaved changes

Comment: Well the second dialog should be. Are you sure you want to exit/close? And then Yes or No. A dialog question should always refer the the operation the user just choose.

Answer (score 0):

According to angular material [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) on you can get result from dialogue box to your grid component. There you can do whatever you want with result.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create another dialog based on the answer from the previous dialog, your best bet is to exit from the first dialog and if there is result, show the second dialog in the afterClosed subscription of the first dialog.

```
const editDialog = this.dialogRef.open(EditComponent, { 
...
}); 

editDialog.afterClosed().subscribe( result => {
    if (result) {
       let confirmDialog = this.dialogRef.open(ConfirmDialog, {...});
       confirmDialog.afterClosed().subscribe( result => {
            ...
       });

    }
});
```

If you are trying to kick off that from the dialog, then you can create a new confirmation dialog from the edit dialog and based on the result from that, return your response back to the grid component.